# AndEngine: How to know whether a Class(extends Sprite) collides with another class(extends Sprite)

Tags: android, andengine

I have two classes, Enemy.java extending "Sprite" as well as another class Bullet.java extending "Sprite".
Now if i want to check whether an object of Enemy collides with Bullet's object,

```
EnemyObj.collidesWith(BulletObj)
```

But, in my case I have too many bullets and too many Enemies.
I can make a loop for it for every EnemyObj & BulletObjs.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        if( EnemyObj[i].collidesWith(BulletObj[j]) ) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

But I want a general solution, if there is anything like this.

```
if(EnemyClass.collidesWith(BulletClass)){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to handle collisions/contacts between bodies, we will use `ContactListener`.if you want  to execute action after contact between Enemy  and Bullet use `ContactListener`